# Where should I store private certificate files in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store a private certificate file so I can use it to validate user files but where can I store it privately. Should I store in storage/app folder or somewhere else ?

Comment: Do you mean SSL certificate? In Ubuntu "_the right place to store your certificate is `/etc/ssl/certs/` directory. Save your private keys to `/etc/ssl/private/` directory_." See [this link](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/ssl-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mostly depends on where you deploy your app.

**Option 1 - application in a cloud:**
If you deploy your app in a cloud the solution is really simple. Just take advantage of services designed for secrets management (e.g. AWS Secrets Manager).

**Option 2 - custom infrastructure:**
In this case, you have 2 options. You can either store your key/cert in a security manager installed locally (e.g. [Knox](https://github.com/pinterest/knox)) or as a plaintext somewhere on your server. In the latter case, it doesn't matter where exactly you store it. It is only important that this location is not publicly accessible. The `storage/app` is OK. Just make sure it's not `storage/app/public` :)